# inner product and bilinear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, bilinear-form

I understand that the inner product of two vectors and its properties. However I do not quite understand bilinear mappings.

- What is the relationship between inner products and bilinear mapping?
- and how could I use this to show that two inner products <**x**,**y**> and <**u**,**v**> of vector space ***V*** have bases which are orthogonal to both inner products?

Comment: A bilinear mapping is a function of two vectors that is linear in each "slot".

Answer (score 1):

An inner product is a particular bilinear form, at least when the field is $\mathbb{R}$. It has the additional property of being positive-definite and symmetric.

Comment: And symmetric. [filler]

Comment: Yes, thank you!